# Cant Copy Activesheet before send it

Tags: vba, excel

I am going to copy a active worksheet before send it out thought outlook, but it gave me a

> "Run-time error '1004': We couldn't copy this sheet".

I have try few commands in below to copy the sheet just don't work:

```
ThisWorkSheet.Copy ' fist method 
Worksheets("Confirm").Activate 
ActiveSheet.Copy   ' Second mehod
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Confirm").Copy ' Third method
```

All this came out error and debug is navigate to online of above code.

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()

Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook

ActiveSheet.Copy ' when debug this code come out error
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
    End If
End With

'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = Range("F4").Value

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Range("B12").Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Order From " & Range("E8").Value
        .HTMLBody = "<font face=""calibri"" style=""font-size:11pt;"">Dear Collegue, " & "<br><br>" & _
                "Please kindly find the attached new order for " & Range("E8").Value & " above." & _
                "<br><br>" & "Regards <br><br>" & Range("F6").Value & "<br><br>" & _
                "Shop : " & Range("E8").Value & "<br>" & _
                        Range("E9").Value & "<br>" & _
                        Range("E10").Value & "<br>" & _
                        Range("E11").Value & "<br>" & .HTMLBody & "</font>"
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With

'Delete the file you have send
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

MsgBox "Mail has been sent!"

Set OutApp = Nothing
'Set OutMail = Nothing End Sub
```

Please helps, thank you

Comment: Does it work if you copy it manually by right clicking on the Sheet tab and copy? Is this code run periodically or only once? If periodically then see: [Copying worksheet programmatically causes run-time error 1004 in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210684/copying-worksheet-programmatically-causes-run-time-error-1004-in-excel). Also try to save the workbook before you copy the sheet.

Comment: I cant copy it manually by right clicking on the sheet tab, it come out Path/File access error: ''.\VBF516.TMP"

Comment: So then this looks not directly like a VBA issue but more like a permission issue. Where is your workbook saved? Did you open it from an email of from your hard drive?

Comment: This workbook is saved on my desktop, so I open it from my hard drive. I check the file authors is other name. But when check the permission in security tab of properties, it show my account have full controls

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you place the file into another directory?

Comment: I copy the file into D drive and the problem still occur

Comment: @TerenceZhong Does it also happen with other files that you cannot copy a sheet (eg. if you create a new Excel workbook put some fake data in, save it on disk and then try to copy the sheet)?

Comment: @PEH My other excel files can copy a sheet within same workbook, only this workbook includes macros can't copy. Also, this workbook is download from outlook attachment. And now I found a odd thing, the sheet can copy only if I save the file as a new file. Then I can run the macro successfully. However, it does not work again if I close the file and open it again.

Comment: I still think this has to do with the issue described in the link I gave you in my first comment. They say a workaround is to save the workbook before you copy.

Comment: shooting in the dark, change this line  `Environ$("temp")` and give it a folder address outside your operating system directory and try again

Comment: @Ibo I will give it a try later, Thank you

Comment: @Ibo since the `ActiveSheet.Copy` line where the error actually occurs is a way before using `Environ$("temp")` it cannot be the issue of that error.

Comment: I had a closer look, I agree with @Pᴇʜ this is not a VBA issue and it must be a security issue or sth like that. You need to try the code on a different computer preferably a personal laptop that is not connected to any server etc, and remove the `on error resume next` to see where the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

The differences between `.xlsx` and `.xls` extensiond could be the cause.

- `.xlsx` files can contain `1 048 576` rows in contrast to `.xls`, which can contain only `65 536` rows on a sheet.
- So VBA tried to copy whole sheet with `1 048 576` to `.xls` workbook that can handle only `65 536` rows and you get an error.
- As a decision you can copy concrete range `A1:A65536` from `.xlsx` book to `.xls`.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same error message. It seems to be rare, as I couldn't find any other mention of it on the web.

The error occurred on a PC of one of my clients, who uses a VBA add-in I developed for him. Since he's in another country I couldn't investigate directly. I suggested he restart his PC (full restart, not just shut down and start up) and that seems to have fixed it. So apparently it was just a temporary glitch in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, and Richard noted, it is rare. As such, I wanted to share my fix for the issue.

One of the cases that makes this issue appear is if you try to copy a hidden sheet in Excel. To copy it, you need to unhide it first.